# ImportError: svn__apr_hash_index_val after install ViewVc

Tags: 16.04, apache2, python, svn

I've had this error after installing ViewVc. The trackback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 4844, in main
    request.run_viewvc()
  File "/usr/lib/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 402, in run_viewvc
    self.view_func(self)
  File "/usr/lib/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 2194, in view_roots
    allroots = list_roots(request)
  File "/usr/lib/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 4665, in list_roots
    cfg.options.svn_config_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/viewvc/lib/vclib/svn/__init__.py", line 95, in SubversionRepository
    rootpath = canonicalize_rootpath(rootpath)
  File "/usr/lib/viewvc/lib/vclib/svn/__init__.py", line 39, in canonicalize_rootpath
    rootpath = _canonicalize_path(rootpath)
  File "/usr/lib/viewvc/lib/vclib/svn/__init__.py", line 23, in _canonicalize_path
    import svn.core
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/svn/core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from libsvn.core import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsvn/core.py", line 28, in <module>
    _core = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsvn/core.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_core', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libsvn/_core.so: undefined symbol: svn__apr_hash_index_val
```

I've tried to install python and cgi module on apache2 again and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: my problem was with a package wihin python-subversion so I installed.

`sudo apt-get install python-subversion`

It installed python-subversion armhf 1.9.4-3.